# Lua add value to json.decoded data

Tags: lua

I am trying to insert new data to json. My json is ;

```
data = {"one":44,"two":18}



arr_stock = json.decode(data)
```

The data im trying to insert is ;

```
result = {"three":5}
```

How can i do it ?

I tried ;

```
arr_stock = arr_stock , result
```

But its not working.

Comment: why do you invent your own syntax?

Comment: You mean + ? I tried comma too

Comment: you don't "try" based on a guess, you refer to a manual and do it correctly how can you expect anything useful from random text

Answer (score 1):

```
arr_stock.three = 5
```

you should first ensure that decoding your json string actually succeeded to avoid errors.

About your code:

`data = {"one":44,"two":18}` is invalid syntax. `data` must be a string if you want to use it as an argument to `json.decode` as `json.decode` will decode a json string into a Lua table.

`data = '{"one":44,"two":18}'` would be a valid Lua string.

Same for `result = {"three":5}`

Assuming `arr_stock` is a table successfully obtained through decoding `data`, `arr_stock = arr_stock + result` is nonsense.

You cannot add a table and a string, unless you have implemented a respective metamethod. What you want to do here is to insert a new field to a table and that's done through assignment.

Please refer to the Lua manual https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/